# Find a value from a range in MS Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone please point out where am i going wrong in the below code. 
I need to find all occurrences of a value in a range for which I am using find command. To start finding the next occurrence, I am using find command again but after the first found cell. the message box for debugging purpose however shows that the 2nd find command is also referring to the same 1st found cell since both the commands have same cell address as output.

Can someone please point out what is the mistake in this. I have already spent a day in this and am still not able to make out the error.

Thanks in advance.

```
Set FoundCell = Range("Act_No").Find(what:=PreActivityArray(i))
If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    firstaddress = FoundCell.Address
    Do
        MsgBox (CStr(FoundCell) & " address " & CStr(FoundCell.Address) & " " & CStr(FoundCell.Row))
        Set FoundCell = Range("Act_No").Find(what:=PreActivityArray(i), after:=FoundCell)
        MsgBox (CStr(FoundCell) & "address " & CStr(FoundCell.Address) & " " & CStr(FoundCell.Row))
    Loop While Not FoundCell Is Nothing And FoundCell.Address <> firstaddress
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FindNext` method instead:

```
Set FoundCell = Range("Act_No").Find(What:=PreActivityArray(i))
If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    firstaddress = FoundCell.Address
    Do
        MsgBox FoundCell & " address " & FoundCell.Address & " " & FoundCell.Row
        Set FoundCell = Range("Act_No").FindNext(FoundCell)
        If FoundCell Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        If FoundCell.Address = firstaddress Then Exit Do
        MsgBox "Another instance of value: " & FoundCell.Address
    Loop While True
End If
```

and also note, that I'm using `If FoundCell Is Nothing Then Exit Do`.
You can't use line `Loop While Not FoundCell Is Nothing And FoundCell.Address <> firstaddress` as in your original code, since if `FoundCell` is `Nothing` then `FoundCell.Address` triggers runtime-error.

Also you can read this:  [.Find and .FindNext In Excel VBA](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Comment: Still the same...the 2nd msgbox command still shows the address of the first found cell...which means it is still not searching after having found the first instance :( :(

Comment: see my updated answer. You don't need second `MsgBox` - because it's odd. Imagine situation when `Set FoundCell = Range("Act_No").FindNext(FoundCell)` returns something..your _second_ msgbox gives you a message with address of this cell. Then, since you're using `Do..Loop While` you appears at the first line of loop (next iteration) and first msgbox show you same message again. In your code using _only one_ msgbox would be enough.

Comment: Hey simoco...i just want to ensure if the 2nd instance of a value in the sheet is being found...if it is, then i need to execute some other set of commands...both these message boxes are just for debugging purpose...and ideally the second message box should give me the address of the next found cell...but it isnt.. :(

Comment: if second instance of a value not found, line `If FoundCell Is Nothing Then Exit Do` exits from loop, so just put all releveant code after it. See updated answer

Comment: okay...i got the mistake that i was doing...the values i was searching for werent in the right range that i had mentioned in the find command...a very very silly mistake that took almost 2 days of mine :) :).... however thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: okay...suddenly i dont know how...but my code is now finding additional values as well...for eg...if i want to find cell with just '3', its even finding the ones that have '13', '23' ,'33' and so on...any idea what could have gone wrong...if you want i can even show you the code..

Comment: change `Set FoundCell = Range("Act_No").Find(What:=PreActivityArray(i))` to `Set FoundCell = Range("Act_No").Find(What:=PreActivityArray(i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
`

Comment: Thanks man...you are a saviour :) 
Its working now...but still dont know why it stopped working before when it was working earlier..

Comment: most likely is that when you're used CTRL+F (find window) in worksheet, you've changed option for looking in partial word instead whole word and excel remembers this state